# using Zxing to scan barcode in image

Tags: c#, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I try using zxing to scan barcode in an image using C#. But it didn't work.Below is my code:

```
var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();
var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Documents and 
                           Settings\Desktop\80979.jpg");
var barcodeResult = barcodeReader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
Console.WriteLine(barcodeResult.Text);
Console.WriteLine(barcodeResult.BarcodeFormat);
```

Comment: can you make sure that their is value in barcodeBitmap variable

Comment: can you provide the Image for download?